# Air restriction about batteries

Tags: batteries, pcb, battery-charging, battery-operated

We are building a PCB that we are about to sell for DIY users worldwide (with components). This PCB is microUSB powered, contains a charger chip, and a battery (probably 18650).

I heard that [there might be](http://www.dhl.com/en/express/shipping/shipping_advice/lithium_batteries.html) **airplane shipping restriction for devices containing batteries**. What are they exactly?

How to be able to send an electronic device worldwide without restriction because it contains a battery?

Comment: If you expand the "Explain" it's quite clear.

Comment: @MatsK Oh yeah, **a good explanation is actually on that page Basj directly linked to** and in the linked-to- pages from there.

Answer (score 2):

International aeronautics are coordinated and kind-of regulated by the IATA.

So, they are the prime source for questions regarding air shipping:

http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Pages/lithium-batteries.aspx

But: That's definitely not the only restriction. In the end, every country has its own laws regarding the entry of goods. How are you planning to ship "without restrictions" to North Korea? The same goes for export regulations. If you're in the US, for example, exporting electronics to Iran might be impossible.

So, "without restriction" is not going to happen. Distribution of goods worldwide is a complicated business, because you might need to know the rules of every single country you ship to, and that's why most manufacturers of electronics don't directly sell to customers, but share their profit with *distributors* and *importers*.